# How to match two strings to one route express.js

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

I've got a single route function that I want to match two different paths to. The idea is to create profile pages for team members of a website. They'll be at `www.domain.com/name`. The issue is, some people have nicknames. So, I need `www.domain.com/nickname` to go to the same place as `www.domain.com/name`.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
website.get('/name|nickname', websiteRoutes.about);
```

The problem is things like `/asdasdfdnickname` and `/namezzzzzzzz` will match as well.

How do I match either the name or nickname only without any extra characters. I believe this is called an exclusive or?

**So here are some working solutions**

Passing in `['/name', '/nickname']` into the routing function.

And from John's answer below: `/^\/?(name|nickname)\/?$/i`

Comment: Can't you just attach the same function to two different routes?

Comment: Yeah, and the function actually can take an array of strings instead of a regex, I just discovered, so I'll probably just do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `/^\/?(name|nickname)\/?$/i` which will match exactly name/nickname only.

This regex means it can optionally start with a forward slash, it will match "name" or "nickname" case insensitively, then it will optionally allow another forward slash at the end.

Comment: He wants to match `name` OR `nickname`. Change the `/` to a ` |` and it would get the job done.

Comment: Doesn't match anything now.

Comment: Yeah, `/^(name|nickname)$/` doesn't match anything. Or at least not /name or /nickname as intended.

Comment: `/^\/?(name|nickname)\/?$/i` ...?

Comment: Looks like 'starts with /' then contains 'name' or 'nickname' then ends.

Comment: I have updated the answer and included an explanation. Don't forget to mark best answer if this is what you were looking for! Thanks.